# XSLT group elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input xml file like the below

```
<FLEX_ATTRIBUTES>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_DESC</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>Bull broke leg</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_TYPE</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>Injury</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_STATUS</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>Settled</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_YR_OF_CLAIM</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>2009</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_AMOUNT</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>7000</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_DESC</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>Stolen tractor</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_TYPE</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>theft</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_STATUS</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>Settled</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_YR_OF_CLAIM</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>2012/ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
<OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE_NAME>FMGP_CLAIM_AMOUNT</ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
    <ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>16000</ATTRIBUTE_VALUE>
</OBJ_ATTRIBUTE>
```

and I am looking to get an output xml in the below format where each claim is put into a PreviousClaim element.

```
<PreviousClaims>
   <PreviousClaim>
    <YrOfClaim>2009</YrOfClaim>
    <ClaimType>Injury</ClaimType>
    <ClaimDesc>Bull broke leg</ClaimDesc>
    <ClaimStatus>Settled</ClaimStatus>
    <ClaimAmount>7000</ClaimAmount>
   </PreviousClaim>
   <PreviousClaim>
    <YrOfClaim>2012</YrOfClaim>
    <ClaimType>Theft</ClaimType>
    <ClaimDesc>Stolen tractor</ClaimDesc>
    <ClaimStatus>Settled</ClaimStatus>
    <ClaimAmount>17000</ClaimAmount>
   </PreviousClaim>
```

In my xsl I have tried using the for-each-group function as below and it will create a new PreviousClaim element for each FMGP_CLAIM_DESC it finds however I am having trouble trying to get the other elements.

```
                            <PreviousClaims>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="../OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_DESC']" group-by="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE">
                            <PreviousClaim>
                                <ClaimDesc><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/></ClaimDesc>
                            </PreviousClaim>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                        </PreviousClaims>
```

I have got it working using some custom built logic but it's not very elegant solution and I was hoping to take advantage of some of the new features in XSLT 2.0 to make it easier to read and maintain.

```
        <PreviousClaims>
        <xsl:for-each select="../OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_YR_OF_CLAIM']">             
            <PreviousClaim>
                <YrOfClaim><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/></YrOfClaim>     
                <!--  <position><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></position>-->
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="../OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_TYPE']">
                    <xsl:if test="position() = $pos">
                        <ClaimType><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/></ClaimType>
                    </xsl:if>                           
                </xsl:for-each>                                 
                <xsl:for-each select="../OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_DESC']">
                    <xsl:if test="position() = $pos">
                        <ClaimDesc><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/></ClaimDesc>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="../OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_STATUS']">
                    <xsl:if test="position() = $pos">
                        <ClaimStatus><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/></ClaimStatus>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="../OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_AMOUNT']">
                    <xsl:if test="position() = $pos">                           
                        <ClaimAmount><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/></ClaimAmount>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>                                                                                             
            </PreviousClaim>
        </xsl:for-each>                 
    </PreviousClaims>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group-starting-with`:

```
<xsl:template match="FLEX_ATTRIBUTES">
  <Claims>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE" group-starting-with="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_DESC']">
     <PreviousClaim>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
     </PreviousClaim>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </Claims>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_DESC']">
  <ClaimDesc>
    <xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/>
  </ClaimDesc>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_TYPE']">
  <ClaimType>
    <xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/>
  </ClaimType>
</xsl:template>

<!-- add similar templates here for the other attribute types -->
```

If you need to change the order then I would still use the grouping and the templates but then you would need to list the order you want by doing e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="FLEX_ATTRIBUTES">
  <Claims>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE" group-starting-with="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_DESC']">
     <PreviousClaim>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_YR_OF_CLAIM']], current-group()[self::OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_TYPE']], ., current-group()[self::OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_STATUS']], current-group()[self::OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_AMOUNT']]"/>
     </PreviousClaim>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </Claims>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer really helpful! The order doesn't matte so this will work perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a full XSLT stylesheet, building upon the answer given by @MartinHonnen.

**Stylesheet**

The stylesheet only has one generic template for `OBJ_ATTRIBUTE` elements. In principle, it could handle other types of attributes as well - given that their structure is the same.

The fact that the element names should not include `_` anymore and are camelcased slightly complicates the matter.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="FLEX_ATTRIBUTES">
      <PreviousClaims>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE" group-starting-with="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE[ATTRIBUTE_NAME='FMGP_CLAIM_DESC']">
         <PreviousClaim>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
         </PreviousClaim>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
      </PreviousClaims>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OBJ_ATTRIBUTE">
      <xsl:variable name="step-1" select="tokenize(lower-case(substring-after(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'FMGP')),'_')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="step-2">
          <xsl:for-each select="$step-1">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)),substring(., 2),' '[not(last())])"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:element name="{$step-2}">
          <xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"/>
      </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

Note that the order of elements is not the same as in your expected output. If ordering matters to you, neither mine nor Martin Honnen's answer is going to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PreviousClaims>
   <PreviousClaim>
      <ClaimDesc>Bull broke leg</ClaimDesc>
      <ClaimType>Injury</ClaimType>
      <ClaimStatus>Settled</ClaimStatus>
      <YrOfClaim>2009</YrOfClaim>
      <ClaimAmount>7000</ClaimAmount>
   </PreviousClaim>
   <PreviousClaim>
      <ClaimDesc>Stolen tractor</ClaimDesc>
      <ClaimType>theft</ClaimType>
      <ClaimStatus>Settled</ClaimStatus>
      <YrOfClaim>2012</YrOfClaim>
      <ClaimAmount>16000</ClaimAmount>
   </PreviousClaim>
</PreviousClaims>
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias should be able to put this to great use now.